# What's the exact name of the regeneration arrow to be able to use it as a custom recipe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to create a datapack, but can't manage to find the exact name for the regeneration arrow as a result of a craft. Tried

```
"item": "minecraft:tipped_arrow{Potion:"minecraft:regeneration"}",
```

but didn't work.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think you can nest quotes like that.

Comment: Just throw one on the ground and use `/data get`.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 problems with your current code:

- `minecraft:tipped_arrow` does not exist. It should simply be `minecraft:arrow` with the `Potion` NBT tag.
- There has to be a space between `minecraft:arrow` and the `{` marking the start of the NBT tags.
- You can't nest quotes like that in JSON files. It makes the parser think you typed in two strings, `minecraft:tipped_arrow{Potion:` and `}` and that `minecraft:regeneration` is just random text. The easiest way is to simply put `'` characters rather than `"` around `minecraft:regeneration` (or whatever potion you're using).

In the end, it should look like this:

```
"item": "minecraft:arrow {Potion:'minecraft:regeneration'}",
```

Comment: Escaping nested quotes with `\"` should work as well. You'll need that if you have more than one.

Comment: Except that "minecraft:tipped_arrow{Potion:"minecraft:regeneration"}" worked in game, not with the datapack...